# How do I pass cell state from one Tensorflow LSTM to another?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I'm writing a German->English translator using an encoder/decoder pattern,
where the encoder connects to the decoder by passing the state output of its
last LSTM layer as the `initial_state` of the decoder's LSTM.  Here's
a sketch of the code:

```
tensor = tf.random.normal( shape = [ 4, 2, 2 ])
lstm_1 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM( units = 3, return_sequences = False, return_state = True )
hidden_1, last_hidden_1, cell_state_1 = lstm_1( tensor )
print( "cell_state_1:\n", cell_state_1 )
lstm_2 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM( units = 3 )
result = lstm_2( tensor, initial_state = cell_state_1 )
print( "result:\n", result )
```

However, when I try to run this, it fails on the `result = ...` statement.  The error message is:

```
ValueError: An `initial_state` was passed that is not compatible
with `cell.state_size`. Received `state_spec`=ListWrapper([InputSpec(shape=(4, 3), ndim=2)]);
however `cell.state_size` is [3, 3]
```

It makes sense to me that the "state_spec" has dimensions (4, 3), where the 4 is the batch size
and the 3 is the number of units in "lstm_1".  What I don't get is, why does it say that
"cell.state_size is [3, 3]".  It seems to me that this should also be 4 x 3, by the same
reasoning.

**Am I missing or mis-using some argument(s) to one or both of the LSTM instantiations?**

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution, although I'm not sure whether/why it works.  The solution is to change the `initial_state` in the call to the decoder LSTM to:

```
result = lstm_2( tensor, initial_state = [ last_hidden_1, cell_state_1 ] )
```

It's not clear how `last_hidden_1` is used in the second LSTM, though.